# Perl Net::SMTP fails on Fedora

Tags: perl, authentication, smtp, sendgrid, fedora

I have the following code which works fine with an AWS instance with Ubuntu but not with Fedora.

```
#!/bin/perl
use Net::FTP;
use Net::SMTP;

use warnings;

use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $now_string = localtime;
my $date = strftime "%d/%d/%Y", localtime;
my $checkdate = strftime "%d/%b/%Y", localtime;
my $username = "apikey";
my $passwd = "REDACTED";
my $from = 'Reports <reports@redacted.com';
my $smtphost = 'smtp.sendgrid.net';

my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new($smtphost, Port => 587, Debug => 1);

$smtp->auth($username,$passwd) || die "Authentication failed\n";
```

The output on the Fedora instance is:

```
Net::SMTP>>> Net::SMTP(3.11)
Net::SMTP>>>   Net::Cmd(3.11)
Net::SMTP>>>     Exporter(5.74)
Net::SMTP>>>   IO::Socket::IP(0.39)
Net::SMTP>>>     IO::Socket(1.40)
Net::SMTP>>>       IO::Handle(1.40)
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x564c8ac970b0)<<< 220 SG ESMTP service ready at ismtpd0027p1las1.sendgrid.net
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x564c8ac970b0)>>> EHLO localhost.localdomain
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x564c8ac970b0)<<< 250-smtp.sendgrid.net
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x564c8ac970b0)<<< 250-8BITMIME
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x564c8ac970b0)<<< 250-PIPELINING
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x564c8ac970b0)<<< 250-SIZE 31457280
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x564c8ac970b0)<<< 250-STARTTLS
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x564c8ac970b0)<<< 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x564c8ac970b0)<<< 250 AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
Authentication failed
```

The code is exactly the same on both instances but with the Fedora instance Authentication consistently fails.

Manually connecting to sendgrid via the command line also works.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Line 16 is empty and the code doesn't contain any `to`. This is not the code you're running.

Comment: I removed the to: email addresses for privacy reasons.

Comment: Since debug output does not show any authentication attempt my guess is that `Authen::SASL` is not (properly) installed. Does this answer your question? [Sending email through G Suite using Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64829009/sending-email-through-g-suite-using-perl), [Perl TLS SMTP send failing on authentication step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65854026/perl-tls-smtp-send-failing-on-authentication-step).